# Change color of title in patternfly donut chart

Tags: reactjs, patternfly

I want to change the color of title in patternfly donut chart. It currently looks like this 
 
[image]

How do I add the style property to ChartDonutUtilization component? I tried to add the style property to the component this way

```js
<ChartDonutUtilization
  ariaDesc="User progress"
  ariaTitle="User progress"
  constrainToVisibleArea={true}
  data={{ x: 'Completed', y: 75 }}
  labels={({ datum }) =>
    datum.x ? `${datum.x}: ${datum.y}%` : null
  }
  subTitle="in progress"
  title="75%"
  style={title: {color: "#fff"}}
/>
```

but I'm getting parsing error on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<ChartDonutUtilization
  ariaDesc="User progress"
  ariaTitle="User progress"
  constrainToVisibleArea={true}
  data={{ x: 'Completed', y: 75 }}
  labels={({ datum }) =>
    datum.x ? `${datum.x}: ${datum.y}%` : null
  }
  subTitle="in progress"
  title="75%"
  style={subTitle: {color: "#fff"}}
/>
```

and check `style` `props` in this [Doc](https://www.patternfly.org/v4/charts/donut-chart)

Good luck :)

Comment: how is this any different from what I have posted already?

Comment: replaced style={title ...} to style={subTitle ...} , have to use target props name as `subTitle` from `title` . Is this working?

Comment: no it's not; style isn't taking attributes like this, that's why i'm getting parsing error